# How do i order the event in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

My sample

```js
$('#cool').hover(function() {
  $(this).css({
    "background-color": "red"
  });
  $('#fool').css({
    "background-color": "green"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <div id=fool>
    <div id=cool>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

code is given below

The problem is i what to execute the cool event after the fool event. in the given code both are running at the same time.
how do i order the event.
how do i run the `cool.css()` after the completion of `fool.css()`.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/cf59f6be/ trying to figure out the desired results

Comment: what do you mean by `cool event` and `fool event`?

Comment: `.css` is not an event.. it doesn't have a duration. It;s applied instantly.

Answer (score 0):

The result of both `.css()` calls will be applied at the exact same time: the next repaint of the page. To be able to add them in any specific order you will have to force a repaint in between the `.css()` calls.

The easiest way to force a repaint is to read `height` or `width` of the element.

```
$('#cool').hover(function() {
    $('#fool').css({
        "background-color": "green"
    });

    $(this).height(); // Force repaint

    $(this).css({
        "background-color": "red"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#cool').hover(function(){
    var dis=$(this);
    $(this).parent().animate({'background-color':'green'},500,function(){dis.animate({'background-color':'red'},500);});
});
```

Comment: Please consider adding more detail to your answer.